# Grey bar appears on navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I recently implemented a navigation drawer into the main screen of my app. For some reason a small grey (or transparent black) bar is being rendered on top of it.
Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
... >

    <LinearLayout
        ... >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

            <fragment
                ... />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_gravity="start">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/list_nav"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Java portion is just your generic list-filling stuff. Let me know if you need more code.

How can I remove this weird bar?

Comment: Maybe it comes from your toolbar. edit your question and add the toolbar xml code.

Comment: Why do you have a `ListView` inside the `NavigationView`? That's not how `NavigationView` is meant to be used. It provides its own list from a `menu` resource. Is the list shown in the screenshot in the `ListView`, or is it the `NavigationView`'s menu?

Comment: Probably it is horizontal scrollbar...

Comment: @MikeM. I use a list view so that I can use a custom adapter to make the icons and text slightly bigger. The items in the screenshot are in the `ListView`.

Comment: Well, if you're not using the `NavigationView` for its features, then you can remove it, and make the `ListView` the drawer. Just make sure to move the `layout_gravity` attribute to the `ListView`, and give it a definite `layout_width`; e.g., `240dp`. It's possible that shadow is coming from one of `NavigationView`'s internal items.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, that fixed the issue. Create an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationView` is a very specialized `ViewGroup` that builds its own internal structure from provided resources. It's not meant to be used as a regular `ViewGroup`. That is, it's not meant to have child `View`s added directly to it, either in layout XML, or in code.

This is not immediately apparent, though, since no fatal error will occur if you do add children to it manually. It is further muddled by the fact that Android Studio's recent Navigation Drawer templates use `NavigationView` as the default drawer `View` in the `DrawerLayout`, with no indication that it is not mandatory that the drawer be a `NavigationView`. A drawer can be virtually any kind of `View` or `ViewGroup`.

In this case, the shadow is apparently coming from something internal to the `NavigationView`. However, since it's not being used for any of its specialized features, the `NavigationView` can be removed completely, and the `ListView` can act as the drawer on its own.

Simply remove the `<NavigationView>` element, and any code associated with it. To setup the `ListView` as the drawer, set its `layout_gravity` attribute to `start`, and set its `layout_width` to an exact value; e.g., `240dp`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked to add

```
app:insetForeground="@color/transparent"
```

to the NavigationView's XML definition.

Answer (score 1):

i add in my activity_main.xml line:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
...
     app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and it works fine!